# Defining a type alias for Hash Table in OCaml

Tags: json, ocaml

I am trying to use [atdgen](http://mjambon.github.io/atdgen-doc/atdgen) and it requires that you define the types of the OCaml objects you're trying to convert to JSON in what it calls an "atd file"

So for Hashtbl.t atdgen generates code which looks like:

```
type ('a, 'b) bucketlist =  
    | Empty       
    | Cons of 'a * 'b * ('a, 'b) bucketlist

type ('a, 'b) tbl = ('a, 'b) Hashtbl.t = {                                       
    mutable size: int;
    mutable data: ('a, 'b) bucketlist array;
    mutable seed: int; 
    initial_size: int; 
}
```

and the compiler throws up a:

Error: This variant or record definition does not match that of
  type ('a, 'b) Hashtbl.t. Their kinds differ.

And I have no clue how to define the alias in a way atdgen would generate code that'd help me serialize the Hashtbl into a JSON. Because I verified in [stdlib/Hashtbl.ml](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/stdlib/hashtbl.ml) and the types defs appear like for like.

I came [across this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784768/ocaml-why-does-renaming-a-type-fail-with-their-kinds-differ), which looked like it could help me, but I couldn't figure out any differences in what was suggested versus what is being generated by atdgen.

Here's how my atd def looks like:

```
type ('a, 'b) bucketlist = [
    | Empty  
    | Cons of ('a * 'b * ('a, 'b) bucketlist)               
] <ocaml repr="classic">
type ('a, 'b) tbl <ocaml predef module="Hashtbl" t="t"> = {                      
    size <ocaml mutable>: int;  
    data <ocaml mutable>: ('a, 'b) bucketlist list <ocaml repr="array">;  
    seed <ocaml mutable>: int; 
    initial_size: int; 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the keys of the hash table are strings or maybe ints, I recommend sticking to a JSON object and [use a wrapper](https://mjambon.github.io/atdgen-doc/atdgen#using-a-custom-wrapper) on the OCaml side.

If you need to support keys of arbitrary types, you probably should use an array of arrays of 2 elements because JSON doesn't offer anything better.

Here is a complete example illustrating both cases:

File `table.atd`:

```
(*
  If the keys of the hash table are strings (or maybe ints),
  use the standard JSON representation as an object:
*)
type 'v table_as_object =
  (string * 'v) list <json repr="object">
    wrap <ocaml t="(string, 'v) Table.t"
                module="Table">

(*
  If you need to support keys of arbitrary types,
  you probably should use an array of arrays of 2 elements because JSON
  doesn't offer anything better:
*)
type ('k, 'v) table_as_array =
  ('k * 'v) list
    wrap <ocaml t="('k, 'v) Table.t"
                module="Table">

type stuff = {
  x: int;
}

type table_ar = (string, stuff) table_as_array
type table_obj = stuff table_as_object
```

File `table.ml`:

```
type ('k, 'v) t = ('k, 'v) Hashtbl.t

let of_list l =
  let tbl = Hashtbl.create (2 * List.length l) in
  List.iter (fun (k, v) -> Hashtbl.add tbl k v) l;
  tbl

let to_list tbl =
  Hashtbl.fold (fun k v l -> (k, v) :: l) tbl []

let wrap = of_list
let unwrap = to_list
```

File `test_table.ml`:

```
open Table_t

let main () =
  let tbl = Hashtbl.create 10 in
  Hashtbl.add tbl "abc" { x = 123 };
  Hashtbl.add tbl "def" { x = 456 };
  let json_ar = Table_j.string_of_table_ar tbl in
  let json_obj = Table_j.string_of_table_obj tbl in
  print_endline (Yojson.Basic.prettify json_ar);
  print_endline (Yojson.Basic.prettify json_obj)

let () = main ()
```

Build commands:

```
atdgen -t table.atd
atdgen -j -j-std table.atd
ocamlfind ocamlopt -o test_table \
  table.ml table_t.mli table_t.ml table_j.mli table_j.ml test_table.ml \
  -package atdgen -linkpkg
```

Output:

```
$ ./test_table 
[ [ "abc", { "x": 123 } ], [ "def", { "x": 456 } ] ]
{ "abc": { "x": 123 }, "def": { "x": 456 } }
```

Answer (score 3):

I know nothing about atdgen, but it seems to me that Hashtbl.t is an abstract type. You can't define it to be the same type as a concrete record type. This is probably what the compiler means when it says the kinds are different.

```
# module A : sig type 'a t end =
      struct type 'a t = { l : 'a list } end;;
module A : sig type 'a t end
# type 'a myt = 'a A.t = { l : 'a list };;
Error: This variant or record definition does not match that of type 'a A.t
       Their kinds differ.
```

(To put this another way, you can't package the internal structure of a hash table into JSON without violating the abstraction layer of the Hashtbl module.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. So how could one serialize a hashtable to json in ocaml if one cannot voilate the abstraction?

ADTGEN requires that you inform it of the structure of the data structure you're trying to generate serializing  code for... and if I can't use ADTGEN for things as basic as a hash-table, then there's surely something wrong with the way ADTGEN  is setup?

On a side note, I tried:
# type 'a myt = 'a A.t;; 

and that doesn't seem to run into any problems.

Comment: As @MartinJambon shows, you really don't *want* to package up the internal data structures of an abstract type. You should package up something more abstract by accessing through the defined interface. This preserves the virtues that are the reason for abstraction in the first place.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. It makes a lot of sense. I think I missed the wraps and unwraps that atdgen supports. The tutorial could do with some real world examples. The data structure that I'm trying to json-ize is huge. Its a graph within a graph with optional metadata sprinkled throughout.